# Label offsets in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I'm trying to write a simple bootloader for x86 and I'm having a problem in understanding how NASM converts labels to offsets when assembling the program.

(This is only a demonstration program)

```
bits 16
org 0x7C00

start:
    mov ax, 0x07C0
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, msg
    call print
    hlt

print:
    ; print char array stored in [ds:si]
    ret

msg db 'hello!'
```

I assembled the code with `nasm -f bin` command. But it does not work as expected. I used `objdump -b binary -m i8086 -M intel -D` on the binary output and found that the lines corresponding to `mov si, msg` and `call print` are translated into:

```
mov    si,0x7c0d
call   0xc
```

so when NASM replaces `msg` in `mov si, msg` with the offset value it uses the absolute offset relative to `0x0000` but when it converts `print` in `call print` to offset it uses the offset relative to `cs` which is `0x07C0`. So when I try to print the character `[ds:si]` does not point to the expected location. The question is why? And what is the right way to do this if I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: That `call` has in machine code relative imm16 offset `+0x0001`, so it is pointing right after the `hlt`, and will work. BTW, it's a good practice to start bootloader code with far `jmp 0000:7C00 + <start_offset>` to make sure the `cs:ip` is "normalized" to this, as some BIOSes will start your bootloader with different variation, like `07C0:0000`, thus all absolute offsets and addressing through `cs` will be wrong with such BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an artefact of the disassembler: it converts relative displacements into absolute addresses.
If you pass it 0x7c00 as the origin it will show the correct value.

```
c:\>ndisasm -b 16 -o 7c00h a
00007C00  B8C007            mov ax,0x7c0
00007C03  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00007C05  BE0D7C            mov si,0x7c0d
00007C08  E80100            call word 0x7c0c
00007C0B  F4                hlt
00007C0C  C3                ret
```

<sup>ndisasm example</sup>

The bug is that you are using 0x7c0 for `ds`, with this value the origin of your code, as seen from `ds`, is at zero not at 0x7c00.

For example, `start` is at the origin, for NASM that is 0x7c00 and a `mov si, start` is assembled as `mov si, 0x7c00`.
At runtime `start` is at the *linear address* 0x07c00 but the pointer `[ds:si]` points to 0x07c0:0x7c00 = 0x0f800 due to the way `ds` has been initialized.

You can either initialize `ds` with zero (`[ds:si]` will point to 0x0000:0x7c00 = 0x07c00) or set the origin to zero (`[ds:si]` will point to 0x07c0:0x0000 = 0x07c00).

As a side note: you can do just fine with different values for `cs` and the other segments but it's something you must remember and be aware of when, for example, you move code around or setup an ISR.
However, you must initialize all the segment registers, including `ss:sp`.
If this is the first time you are experimenting with bootloaders I advise to have `cs` the same as `ds`.
Anyway, in case you wanted to experiment with different values, NASM supports [Multi-sections](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) for the `bin` output format, that's the closest thing to segmentation that it supports.

Comment: The problem was that I did not fully understand what `org` directive does. And hence the inconsistency between origin and segment registers...

Comment: @Kia.celever Glad to know the issue is resolved now :) Out of curiosity, can I ask what was your wrong interpretation of the ORG directive? I sometimes teach these stuff and It would help me know some of the common pitfalls.

Comment: I didn't know the value in org directive was supposed to actually be "the offset" with respect to current segment. I tought it was the absolute (20 bits wide) physical address that the program is going to reside in.

Comment: Thank you @Kia.celever for your input.